# Cannot detach AWS-managed service control policy - access denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-organizations

I have the following statement in my IAM policy:

```
{
  "Sid" : "AllowDetachingAWSManagedPolicies",
  "Effect" : "Allow",
  "Action" : [
    "organizations:DetachPolicy"
  ],
  "Resource" : "*",
   "Condition" : {
     "StringEquals" : {
       "organizations:PolicyType" : "SERVICE_CONTROL_POLICY"
     }
   }
}
```

However, when I try to detach the `FullAWSAccess` policy from an AWS Organizations account, I get AccessDenied, as if my IAM policy wasn't sufficient. I have made sure that there is another SCP in addition to `FullAWSAccess`, so the issue is not that there would remain no SCPs attached to the account.

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strangely enough, the AWS-managed `FullAWSAccess` policy does not count as a `SERVICE_CONTROL_POLICY` even though it is listed as such on the AWS Organizations Policies page.

When I removed the condition, I no longer got `AccessDenied` errors:

```
{
  "Sid" : "AllowDetachingAWSManagedPolicies",
  "Effect" : "Allow",
  "Action" : [
    "organizations:DetachPolicy"
  ],
  "Resource" : "*"
}
```

Another thing I tried to do was to specify a resource that matched `FullAWSAccess`:

```
"Resource": "arn:aws:organizations::aws:policy/service_control_policy/p-*"
```

But that similarly resulted in an AccessDenied error. So I left it as:

```
"Resource": "*"
```